# using verilog task to create a pattern

Tags: design-patterns, task, verilog

I was stuck with this stupid think:
in a verilog testbench, I want make different signals do a simple pattern:

_--------***_*_**

since there are a lot of signals which I want to toggle like this, I created a task:

```
//timescale 10ns / 100ps//

module tb;

reg  rst_chip_n;

    task reset_phase;
    inout signal;
    begin
      signal = 1'b0;
      #(100);
      signal = 1'b1;
      #(100);
      signal = 1'b0;
      #(100);
    end
    endtask


initial begin
  reset_phase(rst_chip_n);
  $finish;
  end

endmodule
```

however, this doesn't work, the simulation time is 300, but the value of rst_chip_n remains always undefined. 
Why ? And how could I create a task which does a pattern like that on whatever signal I want ?
Thank you everybody !

F

Answer (score 2):

Arguments to tasks and functions in Verilog are passed by value, and arguments of type `output` and `inout` are only updated *when the task or function returns*.

So what's happening in your example is this:

1. `rst_chip_n` is initialized to X
2. When `reset_phase` is called, the value of `rst_chip_n` (X) is passed in
3. During the lifetime of the `reset_phase` task, `signal` is updated. This is only internal to the task. If you waveform viewer will allow you to see `signal` within the task you should be able to observe this.
4. When `reset_phase` completes, the value of `signal` will be copied back to `rst_chip_n`

If you allow the simulation to run past time 300, you will see `rst_chp_n` go to 0 at time 300, because that is the final value of `signal` in your task.

I don't think you can do this type of pattern generation with a simple task. One option would be make a small module to drive the pattern and connect the output to the signal you want to control.

Comment: @user1904549 Glad to help... FYI you should accept the answer if it is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to pass in parameters to the task. Since you declared the task in the module scope it will see those variables and use them anytime it is called.

```
module tb;

reg  rst_chip_n;

    task reset_phase;
    begin
      rst_chip_n = 1'b0;
      #(100);
      rst_chip_n = 1'b1;
      #(100);
      rst_chip_n = 1'b0;
      #(100);
    end
    endtask


initial begin
  reset_phase;
  $finish;
  end

endmodule
```